# Use Storyboard to add AutoLayout constraints relating subviews of custom UIView to other views?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xib

After creating a custom `UIView`, how can you use Storyboard to add AutoLayout constraints relating its subviews to views/components outside the custom `UIView`?

In the example below, `SliceView` represents a custom `UIView`. In its .xib file there is a `UILabel`.

After adding a new `UIView` and setting its class to `SliceView`, the new view looks the same in Storyboard. It hasn't inherited the subviews and properties of a `SliceView.` The two screenshots below illustrate the view hierarchy in the `SliceView.xib` and how after transforming a `UIView` into a `SliceView`, the hierarchy remains the same in Storyboard.

So if you want to add a button that is constrained to 10 pixels above the `SliceView` label, how can you do that inside Storyboard?

```
class SliceView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var storyboardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var captionLabel: UILabel!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        if let nibsView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SliceView", owner: self, options: nil) as? [UIView] {
            let nibRoot = nibsView[0]
            self.addSubview(nibRoot)
            nibRoot.frame = self.bounds
        }
    }
}
```

Storyboard view hierarchy:

[image: After adding SliceView]

`SliceView` view hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Actually i dont understand what u want ?

Comment: The subviews of the custom view is not appearing in the Scene Inspector so there's no way to set constraints against them. How do you use AutoLayout against the subviews of a custom view?

Comment: @yankitPatel do you happen to know the answer to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912050/avoiding-blurriness-at-start-end-of-video-even-after-using-setpreferredvideos?noredirect=1#comment57575685_34912050

Comment: No i am not... sorry